# Identity Server Host into IIS localhost and call from Client

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, identityserver3

Server Error in '/' Application.

> IDX10803: Unable to create to obtain configuration from:
>   https://identityserver:444/identity/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: IDX10803: Unable
>   to create to obtain configuration from:
>   'https://identityserver:444/identity/.well-known/openid-configuration'.

All certificate install into local machine using MMC.

Identity Server Application host into IIS and call from client application. that time i facing this issue.

Comment: is the cert belonging to the domain "identityserver", which is what you're using locally?

Comment: I'm using idsrv3test.pfx & idsrv3test certificate.

Comment: If you want to use that domain, use a cert for that domain.

Comment: That cer will work using "localhost" instead of "identityserver". Try that.

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/CustomLoginPage/CustomLoginPage/CustomLoginPage.csproj#L229

Comment: its work with same domain and cert domain name. thanks

Answer (score 0):

your port looks wrong in your authority. Please double check your port, port `444` is for Simple Network Paging Protocol (SNPP)

In your API's authorization middleware check to see if the correct port is on the authority option.